# How can I access an attribute of a selected parameter in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a list of Companies with a ROIC measure. Each Company belongs to a Segment.
I created a parameter to select a Company: [SelectedCompany], and I want to create a SET which includes all the companies except the [SelectedCompany], which are in the same [Segment] as [SelectedCompany].

My set is currently defined by this formula:

```
[Company] != [SelectedCompany]
```

I should add something like:

```
[Company] != [SelectedCompany]
AND
[Segment] = [SelectedCompany].[Segment]
```

But I don't know how to access the [Segment] attribute of the [SelectedCompany].

Just for clarification, I'm making this because I want to compare the [SelectedCompany] ROIC against the average ROIC of the other Companies in the same Segment.

I would appreciate any help on this.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might want to look into LOD calculations, which can be useful for these kinds of comparisons http://www.tableau.com/LOD-expressions

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I'll take a look on that.

One partial solution is to first select the Segment in a quick filter, and then show only relevant values in a quick filter of Companies (which excludes the selected one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit of a hacky way to get what you're looking for. Keep your original definition for the set:

```
[Company] != [SelectedCompany]
```

Create a calculated field:

```
{ FIXED [Segment] : MAX( IIF([Company] = [Parameters].[SelectedCompany], 1, 0) ) }
```

Then drag that field into the Filters card and filter to allow only 1's. This will filter out all Segments except for the selected company's Segment.